# Create an admin-only accessible directory

Tags: c#, .net, security, file, directory

I have an admin app that runs with elevated privileges and I need it to store some sensitive files in a directory that only system administrators can access.

It probably has to do with the following call but I am not sure how to configure it.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\SomePath", new AccessControl.DirectorySecurity() { AccessRightType = ?, AccessRuleType = ?, AuditRuleType = ?);
```

If there is a better way to achieve the same, please let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Found a good implementation [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/createdirectory-security-straightaway-t3714724.html). Will leave the question open for a day in case there are any other suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you encrypt the files instead?

Comment: I say encryption would be the way to go.

Comment: The files are already encrypted. The required access control is to meet regulations. No alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a good solution [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/createdirectory-security-straightaway-t3714724.html).

```
FileSystemAccessRule administratorRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);

FileSystemAccessRule guestRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Guest", FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories | FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, AccessControlType.Allow);

DirectorySecurity dirSec = new DirectorySecurity();
dirSec.AddAccessRule(administratorRule);
dirSec.AddAccessRule(guestRule);

Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\GuestTemp", dirSec);
```